# How To Get Serenata for Atom to Autocomplete / Goto Definition / etc. With Serialized Objects

Tags: php, autocomplete, atom-editor, go-to-definition, serenata

I've noticed that PHP objects no longer work with goto definition, autocomplete, linting, tips, etc in Atom using Serenata once they've been serialized and then unserialized and reinstantiated.

Is there a setting or any kind of a hack to get this to work?

Sure, it's not the biggest problem in the world; but it would sure be nice to be able to use IDE functionality on such objects.

Comment: Just to clarify, Serenata isn't recognizing PHP objects? What other packages do you have installed?

Comment: For my PHP project, including dependencies:
guzzlehttp, lcobucci, nexmo, php-http, psr, ralouphie, stripe, and the zendframework.

For Atom (installed and enabled):
sublime-style-column-selection, aligners for css, js, php, scss, and coffeescript, atom-debug-ui, atom-ide-ui, autoclose-html, column-select, fonts, git-plus, highlight-selected, intentions, minimap, php-ide-serenata, pigments, project-manager, and sync-settings

Comment: But yeah, specifically - it's not recognizing objects that have been serialized then unserialized and reinstantiated. Which, I mean, I guess that makes sense - but is there a way to counter that?